# Why do yout not need to chmod 755 php scripts before execution?

Tags: php, apache, perl, cgi, chmod

Normally you need to do a chmod 755 for a Perl script, Python script or whatever if you like to run it as a CGI in Apache. But why isn't that necessary for PHP scripts?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to grant execution rights, because the file is read by apache with php, not executed directly.

Answer (score 0):

The webserver configuration file tells it that when a file has a `.php` extension, it should be processed with PHP.

Comment: OK. And where is it defined? And can I define another language like Perl?

Comment: On my server it's in `/etc/httpd/conf.d/php.conf`. It loads a module `php4_module` that implements it. I don't know if there's something similar for Perl.

Comment: Maybe `mod_perl` offers similar capabilities, I don't know. If you want to ask questions about server configuration, ServerFault or Webmasters would probably be better places.